# Spark worker is killing the application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I have a spark application running in kubernetes cluster with one master and 3 worker pods. When I submit the spark job,I see that a worker pod is killing the application and the job fails instantly. Attaching the log of the worker which kills the job. I also noticed that the launch command for the problematic worker is not correct.Other workers are showing the correct launch command. Please help to resolve the issue.

Worker log:-

```
23/07/12 12:15:13 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://sparkmaster-0.sparkmaster-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:7077
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20230712121955-0000/0 for Job 1003597
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk-11/bin/java" "-cp" "/u01/spark/conf/:/u01/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx51200M" "-Dspark.driver.port=33143" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "-XX:+UseG1GC" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@sparkworker-1.sparkworker-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:33143" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "10.244.1.239" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20230712121955-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@10.244.1.239:37193"
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20230712121955-0000/0
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20230712121955-0000/0 interrupted
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
23/07/12 12:20:21 INFO Worker: Executor app-20230712121955-0000/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
23/07/12 12:20:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle files associated with the finished executor 0
```

Master log:-

```
23/07/12 12:15:13 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.244.1.239:37193 with 1 cores, 57.6 GB RAM
23/07/12 12:15:40 INFO Master: 10.244.2.12:38819 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:15:40 INFO Master: Removing worker worker-20230712101331-10.244.2.12-38819 on 10.244.2.12:38819
23/07/12 12:15:40 INFO Master: Telling app of lost worker: worker-20230712101331-10.244.2.12-38819
23/07/12 12:15:40 INFO Master: 10.244.2.12:38819 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:15:57 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.244.1.240:33237 with 1 cores, 57.6 GB RAM
23/07/12 12:16:24 INFO Master: 10.244.2.140:46723 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:16:24 INFO Master: Removing worker worker-20230712101508-10.244.2.140-46723 on 10.244.2.140:46723
23/07/12 12:16:24 INFO Master: Telling app of lost worker: worker-20230712101508-10.244.2.140-46723
23/07/12 12:16:24 INFO Master: 10.244.2.140:46723 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:17:48 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.244.2.141:41993 with 1 cores, 57.6 GB RAM
23/07/12 12:19:50 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
23/07/12 12:19:50 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20230712121950-0000 on worker worker-20230712121556-10.244.1.240-33237
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Master: Registering app Job 1003597
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Master: Registered app Job 1003597 with ID app-20230712121955-0000
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20230712121955-0000/0 on worker worker-20230712121513-10.244.1.239-37193
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Master: 10.244.1.237:36488 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:19:55 INFO Master: 10.244.1.237:35713 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20230712121955-0000
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Master: Removing app app-20230712121955-0000
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to /10.244.2.12:38819, creating a new one.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to /10.244.2.140:46723, creating a new one.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to /10.244.2.10:37231, creating a new one.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Master: 10.244.1.240:46296 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Master: sparkworker-1.sparkworker-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:33143 got disassociated, removing it.
23/07/12 12:20:20 INFO Master: Removing driver: driver-20230712121950-0000
23/07/12 12:20:21 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20230712121955-0000/0
23/07/12 12:20:23 WARN OneWayOutboxMessage: Failed to send one-way RPC.
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.244.2.140:46723
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:244) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:186) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194) [spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190) [spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No route to host: /10.244.2.140:46723
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-all-4.1.44.Final.jar:4.1.44.Final]
```

The exception and warning message from master pod log says ,

```
23/07/12 12:20:23 WARN OneWayOutboxMessage: Failed to send one-way RPC.
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.244.2.140:46723
```

I do not know what this message means. Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is two possibilities:

1- It Is possible that your worker pod is being deleted, which is what happens when a deployment is updated for exemple.

Check the worker pod logs to have more details about this issue.

2- It Is also possible that this is related to a memory issues. Your pod memory configuration may not be sufficient to process your data. Try to update the resources cpu and memory in the worker deployment.yml

Comment: I checked the worker pod and logs. Apart from the message that it is going to kill the app, there are no other info. Also, the worker pod is still up and running.
I tried increasing driver and executor memory, but did not help.

In master pod logs, I see "OneWayOutboxMessage: Failed to send one-way RPC." . I do not know what this message means. Please help to clarify.

Comment: did you try to increase the worker container memory and cpu ? not the spark configuration i'm really talking about the container configuration in the yaml file 
resources:
            limits:
              cpu: xm
              memory: yGi

Comment: I had changed only driver and executor memory

Comment: Try to increase the worker container configuration